# Get elements without children using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get all elements without any childs in DOM, excluding span elements.

For example, I have :

```
<div class="test">
   <div class="test2">
      <span>Test</span>
      <p>Test 2</p>
   </div>
   <p class="test3">Test 3</p>
   <h4 class="test4"><span>Test</span> 5</h4>
   <div>
       <p class="test5">Test 5</p>
       <div>
           <h4 class="test6">Lorem Ipsum</h4>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What I want is to get `.test2`, `.test3`, `.test4`, `.test5` and `.test6`.
I want `.test2` because there is a span element in it and I don't want spans. What is the best approach ? How can I test if there is a span in child, I want to get the parent ?

I tried something like this :

```
$('.test').find(':last-child').filter(':not(:has(span)').addClass('last-child');
```

Comment: `I want .test2 because there is a span element in it and I don't want spans.` doesn't make sense

Comment: To be more specific, even if you ignore the `<span>` elements, `.test2` still has a `<p>` child. So why do you want it in your results?

Comment: And `test4` has a textnode too

Comment: This is what you are looking for: https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: In fact I want to get only childrenless elements if they are not span elements.

Comment: @VincentDecaux you want all elements that are either (i) empty (ii) have span as a child?

Comment: Not empty, I want elements without elements inside, and they these elements should not be span ones.

Comment: Maybe the sentence should be corrected into `I want .test2 because there is a span element in it, and .test2 selector is not span (but div instead). I don't want my jquery command to select spans elements (divs are ok).` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  `:has(selector)`. For example

```
var parentobj = $('div:has(span)').parent();
```